# How can i reduce this repeat code in Java 8?

Tags: java

I have the following code that keeps repeating a lot. Maybe there is a way to reduce it but i dont know too much of java. It looks like this:

```
public Optional<byte[]> generateReportA(List<ClassThatChange> request){
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(request)) {
           return Optional.empty();
        }
        
        List<ClassThatNOChange> list = new ArrayList<>();

        
        for(ClassThatChange item : request){
            ClassThatNOChange c = new ClassThatNOChange()
            
            //here is the line of code that changes from report to report
            c.setResult(callMethodA(item.getVariable1(), item.getVariable2()));

            list.add(c);
        }
        
        return Optional.of(callSameMethod(list));
}

public Optional<byte[]> generateReportB(List<ClassThatChange> request){
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(request)) {
           return Optional.empty();
        }
        
        List<ClassThatNOChange> list = new ArrayList<>();

        
        for(ClassThatChange item : request){
            ClassThatNOChange c = new ClassThatNOChange()
            
            //here is the line of code that changes from report to report
            c.setResult(callMethodB(item.getVariable2()));

            list.add(c);
        }
        
        return Optional.of(callSameMethod(list));
}
```

The only thing that change is the callMethodA, or B, or C... but all of them return the same type of answer.

The ClassThatChange is something like this:

```
public class Father{
      private Date date;
      // then the getters and setters
}

public class Son extends Father{
      private String description;
      // then the getters and setters
}
```

All the classes that can change extends from the father.

Is there a way to reduce this repeat code?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please provide additional details.

Comment: What do you mean "repeat code?"

Comment: Was `for(ClassThatChange item : list)` meant to be `for(ClassThatChange item : request)`?

Comment: Is it possible for "call another method that change" to all look like `callMethodA(item)` ?

Comment: Sorry, i had edit my question. With repeat i mean that i have a lot of generateReportA, B, C that has lots of repeat lines.

Comment: Can you change `callMethodA`, `callMethodB` etc to accept the item (instead of a variable list of feilds of the item)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a way to plug in a conversion from the type that changes in each case to the type that is always the same. That could be done with a `Function`, or with a customized functional interface that you define. Here, I'm showing `Function`.

```
private <T> Optional<byte[]> convert(
    List<? extends T> request, 
    Function<? super T, ? extends SomeTypeYouDidNotShow> conversion) {

    if (request.isEmpty()) return Optional.empty();
    List<ClassThatNOChange> list = request.stream()
        .map(item -> {
                ClassThatNOChange c = new ClassThatNOChange();
                c.setResult(conversion.apply(item));
                return c;
            })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Optional.of(callSameMethod(list));
}
```

Then all your duplicate methods would look something like this:

```
public Optional<byte[]> generateReportA(List<Father> request) {
    return convert(request, 
        item -> callMethodA(item.getVariable1(), item.getVariable2()));
}

public Optional<byte[]> generateReportB(List<Son> request) {
    return convert(request, 
        item -> callMethodB(item.getVariable2()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what i needed!